# Wonderware Information Server Process Graphics

Tags: wonderware

I'm using WIS 3.1. In **Process Graphics** I have two Intouch windows: wnd1 and wnd2. They were published with WinXMLExporter. Wnd1 has the button with action: show "wnd2" and Wnd2 has the button with action: show "wnd1". when I select each window in **Panel** (Process Graphics - WindowSet - wnd1 or wnd2), everything is OK. When I periodically (every 40 sec about) push buttons on the each window, another window appeared. it's OK. But when I do nothing for more than one minute and after that push the button I see the error - MessageBox with "error in looking up  window: wnd1 (or wnd2)". Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This error happens after timeout in *Server Manager > IIS Manager > Deafault Web Site > IIS > ASP > Services > Session Properties > Time-out*